# Link of class failed dalvik

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` in the libs folder and have set it in the classpath as well. Still I am getting the following error. Later I get the `ClassNotFound` Error.

```
02-21 22:40:31.975: I/dalvikvm(951): Failed resolving Lcom/package/class; interface 88 'Lcom/google/ads/AdListener;'
02-21 22:40:31.975: W/dalvikvm(951): Link of class 'Lcom/package/class;' failed
```

It was working before only change I did was to move some activities from application to library.

Also if I remove the AdListener interface and its overridden methods it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

After spending 12 hours I was able to resolve the issue on my own. I am answering it here so that it can be useful to someone in the similar situation.

I was ignoring the following warning

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
Versions found are:
Path: /App/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    Length: 349252
    SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
Path: /App Library/libs/android-support-v4.jar
    Length: 337562
    SHA-1: 27c24d26e4c5d57976e6926367985548678e913c
```

I just deleted android-support-v4.jar from app's lib folder and kept the one in library's lib folder and the error was gone.